# Counting numbers of DBpedia wikilink and external link using SPARQL

Tags: r, sparql, dbpedia, linked-data

I am currently querying DBPedia for a list of person names by using the SPARQL package in R. And now I am working on counting of different categories for one person, such as the number of **wikilink** or **external_link**. But I only know to count all the items together per person, such as:

```
    query= "SELECT COUNT (*){
    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Philipp_Melanchthon> ?p ?o 
    }"
```

This just print out the count of all the items for one person, is there any way to print out the count of **different categories** for one person respectively? Many thx.

Comment: You're welcome. You can consider [accpting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer if your question has been answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you pointed out the following query gives you all the relations and objects related to it:

```
SELECT distinct *{
    dbpedia:Philipp_Melanchthon ?p ?o.
}
```

If you want to find out the external links, you need to replace `?p` with the appropriate property in this case `dbpedia-owl:wikiPageExternalLink`:

```
SELECT distinct *{
    dbpedia:Philipp_Melanchthon dbpedia-owl:wikiPageExternalLink ?o.
}
```

Thus count will give you the external links:

```
SELECT (count(?o)){
    dbpedia:Philipp_Melanchthon dbpedia-owl:wikiPageExternalLink ?o.
}
```

Comment: Super!  Thx, I really want to give u a vote, but I don't have enough reputation...

Comment: That last query isn't legal.  It needs to be `select distinct (count(?o) as ?something) { ... }`. Then it will be legal, but still probably not right.  There's only going to be one count, so **distinct** is useless here.  It should probably be `select (count(distinct ?o) as ?something) { ... }`, so that you're counting distinct values of ?o, rather than picking distinct counts of ?o.

Comment: Thanks Jashua, fixed it.